# How do I change certain points on a R scatterplot?

Tags: r, plot

The R script below gives a scatterplot. However, 9 observations in this data set have `age` right around 80 years old.
I want to change these 9 points to be red circles. How would I do this?

```
library(ISwR)
age <- juul[ ,1]
igf1 <- juul[ ,4]
plot(age, igf1, pch = 15, col = "blue")
```

Comment: `plot(age, igf1, pch = ifelse(age<80, 15, 21), col="blue")`

Comment: Hey, and welcome to SO :) I have rewritten your question so it is easier to read and understand. Don't hesitate to inspire yourself from other's posts in order to write yours.

Answer (score 2):

As [lebastnok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2787952/lebatsnok) suggested, you can use `ifelse` vectors to select one different color / shape for each point.

```
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rnorm(50)
plot(x, y, 
     col=ifelse(x<0, 'blue', 'red'),
     pch=ifelse(y<0, 15, 21))
```

in your case, I guess:

```
library(ISwR)
age <- juul[ ,1]
igf1 <- juul[ ,4]
plot(age, igf1, pch=15, col=ifelse(age < 80, "blue", "red"))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: what is the relevance to of 15 and 21? sorry im a rookie.

Comment: @user10001876 No worries :) `15` and `21` are the `pch` values for circle and square point shapes, according to the docs [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.1/topics/points) or [there](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/wiki.php?title=r-plot-pch-symbols-the-different-point-shapes-available-in-r). You have written `15`, maybe because you wanted square dots.

Comment: @user10001876 If this is the answer you were looking for, don't hesitate to mark it as accepted so it'll be clearer for others :)